# Lucene: Retrieve score of a certain tuple?

Tags: lucene

Normally when using Lucene you set a search query and Lucene gives you some results where you can receive the score for each document.

In my case I want to change this procedure:
I have a tuple of my database and want to pass it to Lucene to receive the score for that certain tuple in a Lucene index. Is this possible? And does anyone know how? ;)

Edit: Of course I want the score of my tuple in relation to a certain search query...

Comment: Relative scores have no semantic meaning in lucene.

Comment: Of course I would want the score for my tuple in relation to a certain search query! I'm sorry I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your tuple maps to a document in Lucene index. A document by itself has no score associated with it; it only gets scored relative to a specific query. How exactly do you want to encode your tuple's score? As document boost, or maybe a superposition of field boosts (I assume that you map your tuple members to document fields) + document boost?

So, you have a tuple and a query Q (possibly a complex one) and you need the score of the document from the index that corresponds to that tuple. First fetch the doc id of that document using a simple query (BooleanQuery of TermQueries); then invoke IndexSearcher.explain(Query,int) -- this will give you its score without actually executing Q.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think my problem is to search for a certain Document in my Lucene index. Do I have to make a query search first and check whether my Document is contained in the results? That isn't very efficient, is it? And you said that I should set a custom Similarity object. That is for changing the score, isn't it? But I'm fine with the normal score, I think... ;) Or why should I change the score?

Comment: Maybe you just need to adjust your viewpoint when working with Lucene. Executing a TermQuery (or a BooleanQuery thereof) is not _searching_, but _fetching_. It is blazingly fast. As for Similarity, by default you get the effects of field norm, term frequency and inverse document frequency factored in. If that's what you want, then you don't need a custom Similarity.

Comment: Yeah, that is more of what I wanted. :) But I still don't understand how I could get that certain Document related to my tuple. It would be easy if my tuple had a primary key but that's not neccessarily required. Or what did you mean by "simple query"?

Comment: You should give us more details then. What I supposed was that you are indexing those tuples in Lucene mapping tuple members to distinct Document fields, so at least the tuple as a whole forms a composite unique key. If you make a BooleanQuery constraining each field to a specific value, you are sure to get either zero or one result from Lucene.

Comment: Thank you very much! You gave me the right idea and helped me a lot! :)

Comment: of course. i just didn't know if it is allowed to do so if the answer isn't really fitting but one of the comments.